# Matches only at the end of the string

Tags: regex, postgresql

I'd like to protect the `email` field of the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  email VARCHAR(255) NULL CHECK (email ~* '\A[^@]+@[^@]+\Z')
);
```

What I would like to do is to allow strings such as:

> bob@example

But I would like to avoid strings such as:

> bob@example\nfuu

I heard that the `\Z` constraint allows any chars after another line (with `\n`).

According to best practices in regex, the `\z` is better than `\Z` as it allow only one line, but [it seems to be not supported by PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINT-ESCAPES-TABLE). And the `$` is not better.

Am I true?

Edit:

I tested this:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  email VARCHAR(255) NULL CHECK (email ~* '\A[^@\n]+@[^@\n]+\Z')
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX users__lower_case__email ON users(lower(email));

--

INSERT INTO users (email) VALUES ('\nfoo\n@\nbar\n');
```

Apparently the constraint didn't work: the wrong email was added in the table.

Comment: When you're creating a unique constraint on `lower(email)` rather than using citext, you're making a mistake. Now you either have to have another index on users.email (slow), or you have to make sure to always query it on lower(email) (cludgy and error prone).

Comment: The pattern `'\A[^@\n]+@[^@\n]+\Z'` [works OK](http://rextester.com/PVTY38504). Even `'^[^@\n]+@[^@\n]+$'` works OK, because `~*` is not in multiline mode, by default. PostgreSQL's `\Z` is really other implementation's `\z` (that's why the latter is not supported): `\Z` will never match *before the last empty line* (like in some other implementations). -- Your problem is that `'\n'` is not a line ending, but two characters: `'\'` and `'n'`. `E'\n'` *is* a line ending.

Comment: @Cirus, did it finally work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

Note that negated character classes match any characters *but* those defined in the set. So, `[^@]` matches any chars but `@`, *including newline symbols*. To exclude a newline, just add it to the class.

Use

```
email ~* '\A[^@\n]+@[^@\n]+\Z'
```

As `\Z` only [*matches only at the end of the string*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINT-ESCAPES-TABLE) there is no way this regex could allow a newline in the input.

Comment: With your regex, I was able to add an email with this value: `\nfoo\n@\nbar\n`

Comment: @CirusPolis: But the regex does not match it. How did you define the literal? Please post a reproducible example. I used `E'XY1234Z@ddddf\nff'` and it did not match. Perhaps, you passed a string with ``\`` + `n` char combination (like `'XY1234Z@ddddf\nff'`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I updated my post to show you my test.

Comment: Try adding a string containing a *newline* - `INSERT INTO users (email) VALUES (E'\nfoo\n@\nbar\n');` See http://rextester.com/DDRP12116.

Comment: Do I need to use `E` before the email string to include a newline in the string?

Comment: Also, I didn't understood if `\A` is better than `^`, and `\Z` is better than `$`.
And I didn't understood why `\z` is not supported, while `\Z` is supported.

Comment: If you are using string literals to define the newline, yes. Try `LENGTH('\n')` and `LENGTH(E'\n')`. See http://rextester.com/SDSI49911. `\A` is the same as `^`, just `^` may denote start of a *line* if you specify a multiline modifier, and `\z` is not necessary since `\Z` matches the very end of a string here.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest you review my post for the right way to store an E-Mail address in PostgreSQL.

- [What is the best way to store an email address in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/165923/2639)

Here is some example code,

```
CREATE EXTENSION citext;
CREATE DOMAIN email AS citext
  CHECK ( value ~ '^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&''*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$' );

SELECT 'asdf@foobar.com'::email;
```

For your table,

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  user_email  email
);
```

Comment: This won't allow emails with Unicode TLDs, it is just too restrictive.

Comment: Thanks, very interesting. I would prefer to check it without extension. Just with a regex.

Comment: Create it without the extension using `AS text` instead of `AS citext`. That's the regex either way. Without the extension `foo.bar@foo.com`, is different from `Foo.Bar@foo.com`. `citext` is part of core too.

Comment: Okay. About your regex, my question was more about the beginning and the end: in your answer, you're using `^` and `$`. But it seems to be better to use `\A` and `\z` instead to avoid other lines inside the input. However, `\z` seems not to be supported my Postgres. Instead, `\Z` is supported. Have you an experience about this?

Comment: @CirusPolis `~` can never run in multiline mode. `regexp_matches()` does not run in multiline mode by default either. Either `\A` '\a` or `^` works by default. They all do the same thing. Unless you explicitly add the `m` flag. Don't add the `m` flag and use `^` *(that's what everyone else expects)*. More importantly, use my regex and use citext that actually makes a difference.

Comment: For the record, `foo.bar@foo.com` **is** different from `Foo.Bar@foo.com` per spec, while `foo.bar@foo.com` and `foo.bar@FOO.COM` are not. Yes, most of the actual server implementations are indeed case-insensitive for the username part too, but that's just because they are violating the spec too. `citext` may be use-case dependent to be used, but at least, users of such methods should be warned IMHO.

Comment: Yes, it's true per the spec. In practice, no. And you can see from the question the intent with `lower()` is to side with practice.